# cant start jupyter-notebook from anaconda3

Tags: jupyter-notebook, anaconda3

I get the below error when I try to start jupyeter notebook from anaconda, can anyone tell me how to fix this?:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\mhove\anaconda3\Scripts\jupyter-notebook-script.py", line 6, in
from notebook.notebookapp import main
File "C:\Users\mhove\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\notebook\notebookapp.py", line 81, in
from .services.contents.filemanager import FileContentsManager
File "C:\Users\mhove\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\notebook\services\contents\filemanager.py", line 17, in
from send2trash import send2trash
ImportError: cannot import name 'send2trash' from 'send2trash' (unknown location)

Comment: I am not sure how you installed jupyter notebook, but the import error points to a missing package `send2thrash`. Maybe try to install that into your conda env and then start jupyter again.

Comment: The error message should be formatted to increase readability

Answer (score 0):

This is an import error. You shouldn't see this unless you are able to run a cell in jupyter notebook that has this line: `from send2trash import send2trash`. If so, check whether `send2trash` package is installed in your conda environment. You can do that by running `pip freeze` or `pip list`. If you don't see `send2trash` there, that would mean it is not installed in your environment. In that case run `!pip3 install send2trash`
or `python3 -m pip install --user send2trash`to install the package.